# Elasticsearch backup only hot indices

Tags: elasticsearch, devops

I have a cluster of elastiсsearch consisting of 6 nodes.
5 indexes are created per day (each index consume about 10 to 250 gigabytes)
we now have a snapshot repository (which is located on the NFS share) where these indices are backed up every day, but the fact is that in a year this snapshot repository began to weigh 40 terabytes and the fact is that these are payment logs that are required by law in my country store for 2 years, but we do not have so much space on NFS, and we had an incident when there was a bug on the NFS share and our snapshot repository was damaged and we could not restore it
and then I thought to change the backup process, make a script that will be every day

1. create a new folder on the NFS share with the current date
   (logz-backup-Year-Month-Day)
2. register a snapshot repository to this folder
3. take a snapshot
4. delete a snapshot repository from elasticsearch
5. make an archive from the folder

but the problem is that every time you take a backup to a new snapshot repository, the Elasticsearch makes a full backup of the contents, how can I make it so that elasticsearch only backs up new indexes to a new snapshot repository? I heard about https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-getting-started-profiles-hot-warm.html, is it possible to do something that the indices are hot during the first 24 hours (for backup) and if it's older than day they switched to warm and so that they would not be backed up to a new snapshot repository?
P.S I tried to compress my elasticsearch repository folder using gzip, and got a noticeable compression (from 40 TB it turned out to be 20TB)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, provided you use the same repository, snapshots are always incremental, i.e. a full backup is not performed every time. Only the first time, all indices are snapshotted and then only the diffs are backed up on each new snapshot operation.

The reason you're experiencing a full backup each time is because you create a new snapshot repository each time (point 2). It's a waste of resources and snapshot/restore has not been designed to be used that way. An index that has been snapshotted yesterday and to which nothing gets written anymore since the last snapshot was taken, won't be snapshotted today again. That's the whole point of incremental snapshotting.

Since snapshots are incremental, it's only useful to keep an handful of them (say the last 50 or 100 snapshots). That's what is implemented on Elastic Cloud, for instance.

To help you with this, you can leverage [Snapshot Lifecycle Management](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshot-lifecycle-management.html) (SLM for short). So, after you [create your repository](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-snapshot-lifecycle-management.html#slm-gs-register-repository) on NFS, you can simply [set up a snapshot policy](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-snapshot-lifecycle-management.html#slm-gs-create-policy) where you define an expiration time as well as the minimum and maximum number of snapshots to keep. That way you can always keep your repository size at bay, i.e. the repository size will be very close to the actual size of your cluster (a little bigger, but not 10x bigger).